# C++ Vectors with pre-determined size throwing compile errors

Tags: c++, vector, reference, compiler-errors, non-static

I am very new to C++ and trying to create a simple `Student` class with a vector of scores of type `int`.

Here's my class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class Student {
    string last;
    string first;
    vector<int> scores(10);

public:
    Student():last(""), first("") {}
    Student(string l, string f) {
        last = l;
        first = f;
    }
    ~Student() {
        last = "";
        first = "";
    }
    Student(Student& s) {
        last = s.last;
        first = s.first;
        scores = s.scores;
    }
    Student& operator = (Student& s) {
        last = s.last;
        first = s.first;
        scores = s.scores;
        return *this;
    }

    void addScore(int n) {
        scores.push_back(n);
    }
};
```

For some reason, I'm getting multiple `reference to non-static member function must be called; did you mean to call it with no arguments` in reference to the vector `scores`.

Here's my full list of errors:

```
main.cpp:15:22: error: expected parameter declarator
    vector<int> scores(10);
main.cpp:15:22: error: expected ')'
main.cpp:15:21: note: to match this '('
    vector<int> scores(10);
main.cpp:30:4: error: reference to non-static member function must be called; did you mean to call it with no arguments?
            scores = s.scores;
main.cpp:35:4: error: reference to non-static member function must be called; did you mean to call it with no arguments?
            scores = s.scores;
main.cpp:35:15: error: reference to non-static member function must be called; did you mean to call it with no arguments?
            scores = s.scores;
main.cpp:40:4: error: reference to non-static member function must be called; did you mean to call it with no arguments?
            scores.push_back(n);
```

I've tried many things but still have no idea where these errors are coming from. I'm very new to C++, so please forgive me. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't initialize a data member like this:

```
vector<int> scores(10);
```

You need one of these forms instead:

```
vector<int> scores = vector<int>(10);
vector<int> scores = vector<int>{10};
vector<int> scores{vector<int>(10)};
```

The reason is to avoid initializations that could look like function declarations. Note that this is syntactically valid:

```
vector<int>{10};
```

but it initializes the vector to have size 1, with a single element with value 10.

Comment: Adding `scores = vector(10)` leads to the following error: `main.cpp:22:14: error: cannot refer to class template 'vector' without a template argument list
                scores = vector(10);`

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a constructor in member definition of your class; you need to call it from the initialiser list:

```
class Student {
    string last;
    string first;
    vector<int> scores;

public:
    Student():last(""), first(""), scores(10) {}
```

**Edit** At least this was the way pre c++11...

Comment: And how would you initialize `scores` in the Argument Constructor?

Comment: In the same fashion: `Student(string l, string f) : scores(10) {`, but use juanchopanza answer if you can use c++11 :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use initialization list for this case:
`Student():scores(10) {}`

What is the reason to create vector with 10 elements if you use push_back() next in the code ?

```
void addScore(int n) {
        scores.push_back(n);
    }
```

This code adds 11th element to the vector. Is it the correct behavior for your project?